# Taylor Expansion of $\sqrt{z}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

The question is:

> let $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$, which is considered analytic in $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty).$ Find the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{z}$ at $z=-1$ and determine the radius of convergence.

Now i understand that the radius of convergence can easily be considered to be the point from the origin to the nearest singularity or by using the limsup but either way this all requires me figuring out the power series of $\sqrt{z}$, can someone please tell me if i'm correct so far

$$\sqrt{z} = (z)^{\frac{1}{2}}=((1+z)-1)^\frac{1}{2}$$ which we can recognise as the bionomial theorem with fractional power. then the power series is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}(z+1)^{n} = $$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-3)!!}{n!2^n}(z+1)^{n} =$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{n-1}(n-1)!(2n-3)!!}{n!2^{2n-1}(n-1)!}(z+1)^{n} =$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(2n-2)!!(2n-3)!!}{n!2^{2n-1}(n-1)!}(z+1)^{n} =$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n2^{2n-1}}\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!^{2}}(z+1)^{n} =$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}(z+1)^{n} =$$

with $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$

then it converges for $|z+1| < 1$

the problem is my intuition tells me i've made a mistake and i dont know where.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If i remember right then $$\sqrt{1+z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}z^n = \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n-1)\,4^n}z^n$$

Comment: You lost the $(-1)^{1/2 - n}$ factor. Also, when you apply the binomial theorem, you already make an implicit assumption about $z$, because $\sum_{n \geq 0} \binom {1/2} n x^n y^{1/2 - n}$ diverges for $|x| > |y|$.

Strictly speaking, the question doesn't specify the branch uniquely: if $\sqrt z$ is a branch of the square root analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus [0, \infty)$, then so is $-\sqrt z$. If you want a derivation from the first principles, take $\sqrt z$ to be the principal branch and $f(z) = i \sqrt {-z}$, compute the derivatives at $z = -1$ and apply the ratio test to the series.

Comment: following your suggestion i get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i(-1)^{n}(1+z)^{n}\binom{1/2}{n}$$ with the usual expansion of the binomial co-coefficients. is this correct?

Comment: Correct. To apply the ratio test, you can just use the definition $\binom a n = a (a - 1) \cdots (a - n + 1)/n!$.